# Can't use Expansion Variable in Substring Expansion Variable

Tags: batch-file

I need help with my Batch script please. I am setting a random number successfully, but then can't use it to get a letter by it, it just uses randnumber a text and I can't use the value.

```
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set "string=abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"


set /a randnumber=!random! %% 26
set letter=!string:~!randnumber!,1!
```

See image for where the problem lies: [Code Syntax Problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DqXy6.png)

Comment: You should only possibly need delayed expansion for the last line, so move it down, use normal expansion for everything except for one of them on the bottom line.

Comment: Oh and if the code you've provided is already nested within a parenthesised block, then you'd perhaps find it easier to call another layer of expansion.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Tried to  do that but even if I do that `set /a randnumber=%random% %% 26
   set letter = !string:~%randnumber%,1!`, then both randnumber and letter are emtpy. Even if I do randnumber=12 both are empty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
set letter=!string:~%randnumber%,1!
for %%t in (!randnumber!) do set letterT=!string:~%%t,1!
echo.!letter!   !letterT!
```

Comment: Thanks that did it!

Answer (score 0):

Here's my comment written as an answer for you.

```bat
@Echo Off
Set "String=abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
Set /A Skip=%RANDOM% %% 26
SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
Set "Letter=!String:~%Skip%,1!"
Echo %Letter% is the character after skipping the first %Skip%.
Pause
```

And, `call`ing an extra layer of expansion:

```bat
@Echo Off
Set "String=abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
Set /A Skip=%RANDOM% %% 26
Call Set "Letter=%%String:~%Skip%,1%%"
Echo %Letter% is the character after skipping the first %Skip%.
Pause
```